# How to solve this for q?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

[image]

So far in this, I understand how to get $$(gamma^2/4b^2)(q1)$$, 
but not the bit before the '+' on the bottom line. Can anyone break it down for me? Thanks!

Comment: do you mean $$q_1$$ or $$q_2$$?

Answer (score 0):

from your last equation we get
$$q_1\left(\frac{4b^2-\gamma^2}{4b^2}\right)=\frac{1}{4b^2}\left(2ab-2bc-a\gamma+c\gamma\right)$$
and cancelling $4b^2$ and dividing by $$4b^2-\gamma^2\neq 0$$ we get
$$q_1=\frac{2ab-2bc-a\gamma+c\gamma}{4b^2-\gamma^2}$$